# FPDF Error "Some data has already been output"

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm using FPDF and trying to output a testpage with code like this:

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I searched a lot on the internet, but they are always telling that I have to use a newer version or other things that didn't work on my project.

Here is the full error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/BusinessAnwendungen/fpdf/fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/BusinessAnwendungen/fpdf/fpdf.php(1051): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/BusinessAnwendungen/fpdf/fpdf.php(987): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/BusinessAnwendungen/sites/bestellung_abschluss.php(8): FPDF->Output() #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/BusinessAnwendungen/sites/main.php(86): include('/Applications/X...') #4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/businessanwendungen/index.php(18): include('/Applications/X...') #5 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/BusinessAnwendungen/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 271

I would be really happy if someone could help me.

Comment: Try to use ob_clean() at start and ob_end_flush and end of code

Comment: this helped me. now it works. thanks! :)

Comment: I have given detailed solution in answer block for more clarification

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  <?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
ob_end_clean(); //    the buffer and never prints or returns anything.
ob_start(); // it starts buffering
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
ob_end_flush(); // It's printed here, because ob_end_flush "prints" what's in
              // the buffer, rather than returning it
              //     (unlike the ob_get_* functions)
?>
```